# Youtube video to be available only at 2pm to 2.30 PST everyday

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there an automated way to make a video public only at our desired time on a daily basis?

I see no option on youtube to do this. To automate the process, the best I could find was to upload new video through the Youtube API with "Videos: insert" referred here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert
and then delete. I created a cron job to automate this process on a daily basis but the URL of the video doesn't stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way currently to schedule releases of videos as you can see by the [Videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method there is no were to set the time for release.   Insert just adds a video they are uploaded when processing is completed.

**Work around**

When you upload your video set the video's privacy status.private and then when you want to release it do a [video.update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) and set it to public.  This could be done by creating a scheduler on your own system with a cron job to run it.